# Set default ACL for all currently defined roles in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I would like to set default ACL for all roles (i.e. without using PUBLIC) in PostgreSQL and want to avoid enumerating.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the following way:

Grant SELECT privilege to everyone for all tables (and views) you subsequently create in schema myschema:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO PUBLIC;
```

and allow role webuser to INSERT into them too:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT INSERT ON TABLES TO webuser;
```

and to Undo the above:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema REVOKE SELECT ON TABLES FROM PUBLIC;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema REVOKE INSERT ON TABLES FROM webuser;
```

[Source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)

That's it :)

Comment: Everyone != all roles. What I want to do is to avoid using PUBLIC (Maybe I should have mentioned it explicitly)